# Unexplained error in sqlalchemy running under flask

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I create a Python object to encapsulate a link to existing postgreSQL database using SQLAlchemy under flask. I link to the SQLALCHEMY database using reflection.

The **init** code for the object is here:

```py
    def __init__ (self, app, url) :
        
        app.config ['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = url
        self.db = SQLAlchemy (app)
        with app.app_context () :
            self.db.reflect ()
            self.md = self.db.metadata
            self.base = automap_base (metadata = self.md)
            self.base.prepare ()
```

This code successfully loads a set of tables, including this one:

```
         Column     |           Type           | Collation | Nullable 
     ---------------+--------------------------+-----------+---------
     idlabelstrings | integer                  |           | not null
     category       | character varying(4)     |           |         
     name           | character varying(45)    |           |         
     value          | character varying(16000) |           |         
     locallanguage  | integer                  |           | not null
     owner          | integer                  |           | not null 
    Indexes:
        "localstrings_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (idlabelstrings)
        "localstrings_name_idx" btree (name)
        "localstrings_owner_idx" btree (owner)
    Foreign-key constraints:
        "fk_labelstrings_languages1" FOREIGN KEY (locallanguage) REFERENCES languages(idlanguage)
        "fk_localstrings_owner1" FOREIGN KEY (owner) REFERENCES accounts(idaccounts)
```

Examining the database metadata indicates the program has loaded the foreign key definitions correctly:

```
    locallanguage   foreign_keys    {ForeignKey('languages.idlanguage')}    <class 'set'>
    owner           foreign_keys    {ForeignKey('accounts.idaccounts')} <class 'set'>
```

However, when a select with join is executed, as follows:

```py
        dbase = self.db
        localStrings = self.base.classes.localstrings
        accounts = self.base.classes.accounts
        languages = self.base.classes.languages
        select = (dbase.select (localStrings, languages, accounts).
                  join (localStrings.owner).
                  join (localStrings.locallanguage).
                  where (localStrings.category == category))
```

The following error is produced:

```
    2023-10-11 18:59:41,072] ERROR in app: Exception on /liststrings [GET]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\context.py", line 1792, in _join
        right = right.entity
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 1327, in     __getattr__
        return self._fallback_getattr(key)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 1296, in _fallback_getattr
        raise AttributeError(key)
    AttributeError: entity

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
        response = self.full_dispatch_request()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.dispatch_request()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
        return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "endpoints\application\app.py", line 124, in stringLister
        result = dataSrc.getStrings ('en', 'wcs', 'public')
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "endpoints\application\dblink.py", line 92, in getStrings
        return dbase.session.execute (select).scalars () #.mappings ()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\scoping.py", line 738, in execute
        return self._proxied.execute(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2262, in execute
        return self._execute_internal(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2144, in _execute_internal
        result: Result[Any] = compile_state_cls.orm_execute_statement(
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\context.py", line 293, in orm_execute_statement
        result = conn.execute(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1412, in execute
        return meth(
               ^^^^^
      File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 516, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1627, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, extracted_params, cache_hit = elem._compile_w_cache(
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 704, in _compile_w_cache
    compiled_sql = self._compiler(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 316, in _compiler
    return dialect.statement_compiler(dialect, self, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 1426, in __init__
    Compiled.__init__(self, dialect, statement, **kwargs)
  File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 867, in __init__
    self.string = self.process(self.statement, **compile_kwargs)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 912, in process
    return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py", line 143, in _compiler_dispatch
    return meth(self, **kw)  # type: ignore  # noqa: E501
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 4585, in visit_select
    compile_state = select_stmt._compile_state_factory(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\base.py", line 687, in create_for_statement
    return klass.create_for_statement(statement, compiler, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\context.py", line 1162, in create_for_statement
    self._setup_for_generate()
  File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\context.py", line 1197, in _setup_for_generate
    self._join(query._setup_joins, self._entities)
  File "endpoints\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\context.py", line 1794, in _join
    raise sa_exc.ArgumentError(
    sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Join target localstrings.owner does not refer to a mapped entity
```

Can anyone tell me why the select routine fails to identify the join columns as mapped entities?

Comment: Could you post the code of the class `self.base.classes.localstrings` to show how the relationships are declared ?

Comment: The relationships are imported from the database metadata using the reflect and automap_base methods, which (according to the documentation) generate the mappings automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `join` clauses should refer to ORM classes, rather than foreign key columns.

This should work:

```py
select = (dbase.select (localStrings, languages, accounts).
          join (accounts).
          join (languages).
          where (localStrings.category == category))
```

The generated SQL would be similar to this:

```sql
SELECT localstrings.idlabelstrings,
       localstrings.category,
       localstrings.locallanguage, 
       localstrings.owner,
       languages.idlanguage, 
       accounts.idaccounts 
  FROM localstrings 
  JOIN accounts 
  ON accounts.idaccounts = localstrings.owner 
  JOIN languages 
  ON languages.idlanguage = localstrings.locallanguage 
  WHERE localstrings.category = ?
```

SQLAlchemy uses the foreign key definitions to create the `ON` clauses in the query.  If `localstrings.owner` and `localstrings.locallanguage` where not defined as foreign keys then you would need to tell SQLAlchemy how to make the joins:

```py
select = (
    sa.select(localStrings, languages, accounts)
    .join(accounts, localStrings.owner == accounts.idaccounts)
    .join(languages, localStrings.locallanguage == languages.idlanguage)
    .where(localStrings.category == category)
)
```

Finally, note that Automap will [automatically construct relationships](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/automap.html#relationship-detection) if it can detect them, so you can also use these relationships to express the join:

```py
select = (
    sa.select(localStrings, accounts, languages)
    .join(localStrings.accounts)
    .join(localStrings.languages)
    .where(localStrings.category == category)
)
```

Comment: This works very well. Thank you very much!